# Ubuntu upgrade to blank screen with blinking cursor

Tags: dual-boot, 19.10

I was asked to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 on my dell xps 13 running dual Windows/Ubuntu. I started the process and left.

Came back to a blinking cursor and no matter what I do nothing happens. Can’t even turn off the machine. Tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>F12</kbd> to no avail.
Update:
I did a hard reset and managed to reboot but when I booted Ubuntu I got this kernel panic message...

Comment: I tried Fn+Alt+REISUB and this gave me some lines of text sysrq:loglevel... But then nothing happened

Comment: can you boot the previous kernel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: There were the options of booting up to some other versions - I tried that but while it asked for my password etc it finally said "Aw snap, something has gone wrong" and asked me to log out. When I clicked the log out button the screen slightly changed but then stayed in that position.

Comment: After playing around with Ubuntu options and using recovery mode I managed to fix it and it appears to work at the moment. What I did was reboot my computer by holding the power button down for 15-20 seconds. Then it rebooted to the dual boot screen. I chose advanced Ubunto options. There were 3 versions + their recovery modes that I could chose from. I chose one of the recovery versions and chose to reinstall some packages and then it worked.